# jQuery iScroll : Scroll doesn't end with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iscroll

I'm using iScroll for horizontal scroll for a list at the starting point it is behaving normal but when I scroll towards end (right to left) even my content ends but it will keep on scrolling to some extent. I don't know what I'm missing in it 
Fiddle for the same is http://jsfiddle.net/mantrig/wvypmw0g/1/

Below is my function initialization

```
function loaded () {
 myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { eventPassthrough: true, scrollX: true,    scrollY: false, preventDefault: false });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  #scroller {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
      width: 2400px;
      ...
}
```

you set the width 2400px;

http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/horizontal/

this demo works cause it set the width of `#scroller`  5000px with 50*100px  li.

it's not Inline style. so it is not writed by iScroll ( javascript );

but you have to set your `#scroller`  yourself;

Comment: It doesn't matter if I set it to 2400px or 2000px coz this #scroller will set width for the inner content ie. <li> tag.

Comment: iScroll won't do that for you

Comment: Hmm thanks!! Got the point :) There was some another issue with this problem to be specific `#scroller ul { width:50%; }` was not required!!